# Render logged in user photo in the web Channel Bot framework V4

Tags: web, botframework, photo, channel

The below code in the bot framework renders the photo in the Bot Emulator but not in web channel. 
How to get the user photo render in the web channel ?

```
        var reply = context.Activity.CreateReply();
        var photoResponse = await client.GetPhoto();
        var photoText = string.Empty;
        if (photoResponse != null)
        {
            var replyAttachment = new Attachment(photoResponse.ContentType, photoResponse.Base64string);
            reply.Attachments.Add(replyAttachment);
        }
```

reply.Text = $"Hello  {photoText} {user.DisplayName} [{user.Mail}] How can I help you today?";

Comment: Are you getting any error or something?

Comment: The error message I got when I debug is  - "Message Size Too Big"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using directline , it supports only 4MB message size, the base64string of your image might be very large , causing the message to exceed 4MB. This restriction is not there in emulator that's why you are not getting the error in emulator

Try using contenturl instead of base64string and check if it is working.

Comment: Tried no doesn't work. I wanted to render the logged in user (Azure AD) image in the Web Channel. Is there any other option ?

Comment: @SelvakumarRathinam , are you  using directline as connector?

Comment: @ChithambaraKumar is right about file sizes - it is channel specific, so your mileage will vary. What is the size (compressed and uncompressed) of the image you are trying to send...the file size as it sits on your computer/server?